# apache kafka NoReplicaOnlineException

Tags: apache-kafka

Using Apache Kafka with a single node (1 Zookeeper, 1 Broker) I get this exception (repeated multiple times):

```
kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica in ISR for partition __consumer_offsets-2 is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], ISR brokers are: [0]
```

What does it mean? Note, I am starting the KafkaServer programmatically, and I am able to send and consume from a topic using the CLI tools.
It seems I should tell this node that it is operation in standalone mode - how should I do this?

This seems to happen during startup.

Full exception:

> 17-11-07 19:43:44 NP-3255AJ193091.home ERROR [state.change.logger:107]
>   - [Controller id=0 epoch=54] Initiated state change for partition __consumer_offsets-16 from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed
>                                                                 kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run       ShutdownableThread.scala:
>   64
>                               kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread.doWork
>   ControllerEventManager.scala:   52
>                                                                      kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time               KafkaTimer.scala:   31
>              kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread$$anonfun$doWork$1.apply
>   ControllerEventManager.scala:   53 (repeats 2 times)
>       kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread$$anonfun$doWork$1.apply$mcV$sp
>   ControllerEventManager.scala:   53
>                                                  kafka.controller.KafkaController$Startup$.process
>   KafkaController.scala: 1581
>                                                             kafka.controller.KafkaController.elect          KafkaController.scala:
>   1681
>                                              kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover
>   KafkaController.scala:  298
>                                                     kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup
>   PartitionStateMachine.scala:   58
>                           kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange
>   PartitionStateMachine.scala:   81
>                                                scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach
>   TraversableLike.scala:  732
>                                                           scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach
>   HashMap.scala:  130
>                                                      scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry
>   HashMap.scala:   40
>                                              scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry
>   HashTable.scala:  236
>                                          scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply
>   HashMap.scala:  130 (repeats 2 times)
>                               scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply
>   TraversableLike.scala:  733
>          kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply
>   PartitionStateMachine.scala:   81
>          kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply
>   PartitionStateMachine.scala:   84
>   kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange
>   PartitionStateMachine.scala:  163
>                                     kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition
>   PartitionStateMachine.scala:  303
>                                       kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader 
>   PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:   65
>   kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica in ISR for partition
>   __consumer_offsets-16 is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], ISR brokers are: [0]

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Paizo Not that I remember - switched to Apache Pulsar (not because of that issue though)